# What is the best practice to store username and password on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, passwords

Is there a best practice way to store username and password on the iPhone? I am looking for something that is obviously secure but will also keep the info between app updates.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the Apple Keychain.

```
+ (NSString *) getPasswordForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error;

+ (void) storeUsername: (NSString *) username andPassword: (NSString *) password forServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName updateExisting: (BOOL) updateExisting error: (NSError **) error;
```

> The first method allows you to request
>   the password associated with an
>   existing username for a particular
>   service name (I’ve just been using the
>   name of my app as a service name). The
>   second allows you to store a
>   username/password/service name combo,
>   and allows you to specify whether or
>   not the appropriate keychain item
>   should be updated with the provided
>   password if an existing one is found
>   that matches the username and service
>   name pair. The last parameter of each
>   is a reference to an NSError object
>   which will contain lower level error
>   information if something goes wrong
>   (and be nil if it does not).

For more information see [his blog](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code)

Comment: is the password returned in plaintext?

Comment: when I add that class to my project I get a bunch of weird errors such as   
"_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from: _kSecAttrAccount$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
"_SecItemDelete", referenced from: +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
"_kSecReturnAttributes", referenced from: _kSecReturnAttributes$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
"_kSecClass", referenced from: _kSecClass$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
"_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from: _kSecClassGenericPassword$non_lazy_ptr in SFHFKeychainUtils.o

Comment: What's the best practice for storing the username value? Is there a way to find any usernamees, given only the ServiceName?

Answer (score 5):

The [keychain](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: That link is for the Mac OS X keychain.  Here's the link for the iPhone version (they're slightly different): http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html

Answer (score 3):

Use the Keychain, here is [some code](http://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security) to make it very easy. Works on the device and simulator.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Generic Keychain](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GenericKeychain/listing11.html) example source.  That's the way to go IMHO