# store parameters in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I try to store parameters in iphone application

for example I want to store username and password after login.

And next time when I re-open iphone application, I can re-get that username and password to login automatically.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best practice to store username and password on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538031/what-is-the-best-practice-to-store-username-and-password-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLLite is a good way of storing APP. data.  Here is a good beginner tutorial:

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Answer (score 3):

For security related information you really should use the [keychain](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSUserDefault. Read about it here [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Not for the password.  Use keychain as Nikolai wrote.

Comment: Yeah, it should not for the password:)