# How know if there is a NSUserDefault?

Tags: iphone, comparison, nsstring, nsuserdefaults

What condition do I use to know it the NSUserDefaults I use?

```
NSUserDefaults *preftest;
preftest=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *opening = [preftest stringForKey:@"opening"];
```

This is the way I'm getting the datas. I want to get into the if condition if the preftext stringForKey:@"opening" doesn't already exist.... So I tried :

```
if (opening == nil) {
    ...
    NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [pref setObject:@"OK" forKey:@"pass"];
    NSString *finalfr = [pref stringForKey:@"opening"];
    NSLog(@"(here's the new value of opening: %@ )", finalfr);
    ...
}

if (opening != nil) {
    NSLog(@" != nil");
    // http request}
```

But inded, it doesn't work.

Thanks to help me !!

Comment: NSUserDefaults acts just like a NSDictionary – if there is no value for a key, it returns nil, so your if condition should work. How do you know that it does not?

Comment: I've put [pref setObject:@"OK" forKey:@"pass"]; to set the NSUserDef... Appareltly, the error would be caused because of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get into the if condition if
>   the preftext stringForKey:@"opening"
>   **doesn't** already exist....

But you are testing if it does exist with `opening != nil`.
If you want to test if it does NOT exist, it would be `opening == nil` or just `!opening`.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *opening = [prefs stringForKey:@"opening"];

if (!opening) {
    [prefs setObject:@"OK" forKey:@"opening"];
    opening = [prefs stringForKey:@"opening"];
    NSLog(@"(here's the new value of opening: %@ )", opening);
    // prints: (here's the new value of opening: OK )
}
```

Comment: @albertamg : so it's a problem from   "[pref setObject:@"OK" forKey:@"pass"];" :-/

Comment: @clement: `stringForKey:` returns `nil` if the default does not exist or does not contain a string. So, if you compare `opening == nil`the first time it will get into the if. If you set the default within the if, the second time it won't get into the if. Your original code only gets into the "if" if the default already exists.

Comment: @albertamg : I've updated the first post with the current code that's running ;-)

Comment: @clement: what is the key "pass"? What are you trying to accomplish here? In your new code, `finalfr` will always be `nil`...

Comment: @clement: check the code I added to my answer, is that what you want to do?

Comment: @albertamg : Thank you! The condition (!opening) doesn't run. I've put (opening != nil ) and it works well apparently. Now How Can I delete all the NSUserDefaults on the virtual device to see how it runs ???

Comment: @clement: wait, `!opening`and `opening != nil` are opposite. What do you mean it doesn't run? On the other hand, the easiest way to reset the NSUserDefaults data in the iPhone simulator is to remove the app from the simulator-- just like you'd remove it from a real phone

Comment: OK, thank you. I'm in trouble for this day aparrently. I understood the NSUSerdefault Lesson, Thank you. Now, I'm using the same NSUserDefaults in three differents class and the app sometimes have to be restart 2 or 3 times before the NSUserdefaults are fine overall... is it normal?

Comment: I save login and password in NSUserDefaults, how can I make it better? if someone change it , the user will'nt be able to use the app directly, he propably need to restart it once or more... There is a better way to implement the saving of pass:login ??? THANKS

Comment: @clement: Yes, use the keychain. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538031/what-is-the-best-practice-to-store-username-and-password-on-the-iphone)

Comment: Done ;-) But I asked another question about the keychains lool ... I'm a real noob apparently

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of comparing the pointer against nil, you could compare the contents against an empty string [opening isEqualToString: @""], which returns a boolean.

Comment: Just a quick note - this saved me growing gray hairs:-) it may not have been the answer for this question, but sure answered mine:-) +1 Vote