# how to implement keepSignIn functionality in iphone

Tags: ios, authentication, storing-information

I want to implement "keep me SignIn" in my login screen. In my Screen check mark is placed, when I check that mark the login Id and Password need to be maintained at that user.

I thought User defaults are there, other than that please suggest the better way.

Comment: you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538031/what-is-the-best-practice-to-store-username-and-password-on-the-iphone

Comment: or if you already use a database, you can store it there too. also a good way if you have to handle multiple user/server relations and decide for each if you want to store it there or not :P